# How to only clone a git submodule

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules, git-clone

is there a way to get the information from a server which commit is selected in a submodule without cloning the whole repository? 
The goal is to clone only a specified submodule 'jenkins-config' so we need the URL (we know this already) and the commit.

Use Case: 
We want to use a Jenkins job configuration which specifies what to do with the checked out sources in our Pipeline. Because we do not know what is configured we first want to clone only the configuration, process it and then check out the whole repository (e.g. on the correct node).

We would really like to have the configuration next to the sources of the repository to be built. This is why we had the idea to use a "config submmodule" to include and specify the valid configuration (valid configuration is specified by the SHA of the submodule).
This would also enable to select a specific configuration for your branch. Also the maintenance of configurations for different repositories would be quite comfortable using different branches in the configuration-repository (pull changes).

Any ideas how to solve this? 
 - Config in sandbox next to sources
 - Check out config only (without the rest of the repository)

Comment: In .gitsubmodules you can get the git reference to submodules. Simply clone it as a normal repository.

Comment: That is exactly what I plan to do - clone the submodule as normal repo. 

My question Is: How to get the submodule commit SHA from the main Repository without having to clone it

Answer (score 1):

In `.gitmodules` you can get the git reference to submodules.

To get the commit SHA, use `git submodule status`, this will print the SHA-1 of the currently checked out commit for each submodule.

Comment: This  I can only do after cloning and checking out the whole repository 

My question Is: How to get the submodule commit SHA from the main Repository without having to clone it

Comment: You can clone just the last commit with `git clone --depth 1`